# Shell reads the file line by line, but after each line it says not found. What am i missing?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to create a shell script to create users and create/add each to 
a group from a list in a txt file in ubuntu 18.04. I've been having trouble reading the input file.

Sorry, i'm a beginner on scripting, but I have experience in other languages.

I've tried switching between while and for loops (didn't matter) and i've fixed the path so that it can read the file, but after each line it says "bob: not found". Right now i just have it echoing while i try to fix it.

Here is my shell script so far:
  GNU nano 2.5.3              File: shell_lab

```
#!/bin/sh
# test
cd "$(dirname "$0")"

echo "script running"

for line in $(./input.txt)
do
        echo "$line"
done
```

And here is my input file (in the same directory):

GNU nano 2.5.3              File: input.txt

```
bob
larry
joe
```

I expected to just get echoed back:
bob
larry
joe

And here is what i got instead:
konather@ubuntu:~$ sudo ./shell_lab

```
script running
./input.txt: 1: ./input.txt: bob: not found
./input.txt: 2: ./input.txt: larry: not found
./input.txt: 3: ./input.txt: joe: not found`
```

i have also tried this one i found with the same result:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in `./input.txt`
do
echo $i
# echo $i"123" | passwd "$i" --stdin
# echo; echo "User $username's password changed!"
done
```

The above was solved, another question below

i have one more problem slightly unrelated. i'm now trying to automate the password creation. i've gotten as far as echoing the password from the input.txt file in a pipe, but i don't think it is actually responding to the prompts for me.

`while read u1 p1
 do
  echo "$p1" |echo "$p1"| passwd $u1
  # echo "$u1 had the password changed to $p1"
 done < input.txt`
Result:
`script running Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: Authentication token manipulation error passwd: password unchanged`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(./input.txt)` is a *command substitution* attempting to invoke the command `./input.txt`. From your description `input.txt` isn't an executable file that produces a list, but instead a text file containing:

```
$ cat input.txt
bob
larry
joe
```

If you want to loop over the lines in the file, you need to *redirect* the file as input. You can do so just by including the redirection operator within your command substitution, e.g. `$(< ./input.txt)`, but as mentioned in the comment, you are better of redirecting the file to a `while` loop, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
# test
cd "$(dirname "$0")"

echo "script running"

while read line
do
    echo "$line"
done < input.txt
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh test.sh
script running
bob
larry
joe
```

You should protect against a file without a POSIX end-of-file (e.g. without a `'\n'` after the final line), by checking whether `line` is initialized by `read`, e.g.

```
while read line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
    echo "$line"
done < input.txt
```

This will allow you to read and output the final line regardless of whether there is a proper line ending after the final line of text in your input file.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: i have one more problem slightly unrelated. i'm now trying to automate the password creation. i've gotten as far as echoing the password from the input.txt file in a pipe, but after it asks for me to retype to confirm the password, the second echo will go after the prompt. `while read u1 p1
do
 echo "$p1" |echo "$p1"| passwd $u1
# echo "$u1 had the password changed to $p1"
done < input.txt`

Result:
`script running
Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
`

Comment: Oh, you will need to use a chat program like `expect`. The entry for `passwd` is not simply waiting for a variable to be passed. It is better to simply create the account with a temporary or expired password and force the user to change it. If you note in `man 1 passwd`, there is no option for passing the password as an argument. There is an old article [Script to Add User With Password](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-write-shell-script-to-add-user.html) that may help. See also `useradd -p ...` and also the warning in `man useradd`.

Comment: figures, I had seen expect when I was researching it, but I figured there had to be an easier way. guess not. I'll have to ask what is wanted in order to continue. Either that or i'll just give a temp password. Tomorrow's problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure, no problem. This is really one of those "corner-cases" where the security surrounding the password entry trumps the ability to easily pass a variable.

Answer (score 0):

David answered my first question (THANK YOU!)

My second question was how to input a password from a text file to answer the prompts when changing a user's password. However, this was not possible without using expect so I really didn't want to do that. I talked with a classmate and he used something much easier and obvious that I had missed. I used useradd with the following options:
`useradd -m $u1 -p $p1`
$u1 being username and $p1 being the password from the input.txt file.

i'm not done with the homework yet, but thank you. hope this can help someone else.